# How to run a powershell script in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to run a `PowerShell` script inside a `terraform` script. I tried to use the local-exec function but it throws the following error.

> Error: Unknown root level key: provisioner

I have included the script below.

I would be glad if someone could provide me with a solution.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  inline = ["powershell.exe -File C:\\Users\\Boopathi Kumar\\Downloads\\poscript1.ps1"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) must be ran as part of a resource rather than a top level resource.

Normally this would be ran against an instance such as with the examples given in the above linked docs:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${self.private_ip} > file.txt"
  }
}
```

Which writes the IP address of the instance to a file local to wherever Terraform is being ran.

If you don't have any link to a resource at all (you just want something to happen regardless of any resources changing) you can use the [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) which is designed for this purpose.

As mentioned in the [`local-exec` docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html#interpreter-examples) you can use it like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "example2" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "Get-Date > completed.txt"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can you help me to use the PowerShell script inside the provisioner rather than using the "command" option.

Comment: Just replace `-Command` with `-File` like you would when running it not in Terraform.

Comment: I gave the file path inside command parameter and replaced the -Command with -File and it worked just fine.

Comment: How to pass parameters to the script while calling them inside the provisioner.

Comment: That's probably worth a separate question. It's also one I don't know the answer to as I don't use Powershell.