# calling Powershell script from Terraform script

Tags: powershell, terraform

I am trying to execute a powershell script from a terraform script. The powershell commands in the file is not being recognized while execution. Below is the code:

```
resource "null_resource" "example2" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    
    command = "powershell -file ./sample.ps1"
  }
}
```

Below is the error:
null_resource.example2 (local-exec): Add-AzIotHubDevice : The term 'Add-AzIotHubDevice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSX1b.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is already answered here:
[How to run a powershell script in terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572669/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-in-terraform)

Also, I recommend calling the exact powershell .exe you want. Some servers have PowerShell v5 and v7.  Execution policy can cause issues too.

Recommend command that you can combine with the other answer:
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file "./sample1.ps" -ExecutionPolicy "Bypass"

another example:
https://ripon-banik.medium.com/run-powershell-script-in-terraform-54d6586c2827